# Suma de datos para mostrar

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola tengo este detalle , tengo un codigo php que inserta cantidades de 40 en 40 con cada escaneo que se da , y se manda a la base de datos , como puedo hacer para traer esos datos en suma total y mostrarlos 
ejem: base de datos tiene 5 registros de 40 , muestre resultado 200 
Gracias

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM escan1 WHERE etiqueta1 = '40' ")) {

    /* determinar el número de filas del resultado */
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    printf($row_cnt);

    /* cerrar el resulset */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
mysqli_close($link);
```

con este codigo solo me cuenta los registros

Gracias mira anexo el codigo donde inserta y de donde ocupo traer datos saludos

```
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

                 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO escan1(etiqueta1)VALUES ('".$_POST["etiqueta1"]."')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
         echo "Good"  ;

        }
        $conn->close();
     }
```

?>

if(! ("autofocus" in document.createElement( "input" ) ) )
    {
        document.getElementById( "buscar" ).focus();
        }

con este codigo inserto en la base de datos y ocupo sacar la suma de aqui saludos

[image: algo asi esta , captura codigo de barras numero 40 y ocupo se vaya sumanado 40 en 40 saludos]

Comment: !Buenas! Leyendo por encima el código, no veo ningún operador para realizar la suma. Deberías de crear, por ejemplo, una variable donde almacenar el resultado de la suma que te interese, y después obtenerla. Espero haberte ayudado, o al menos aclarado un poco. Soy nuevo por aquí también :)

Comment: Gracias tengo una base de datos donde almaceno los registros pero ocupo sumarlos , en sql se que es SELECT SUM(columna) from tabla solo que quiero que sea en PHP y me haga eco con el resultado

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUM(etiqueta1) AS sumaTotal FROM escan1)) {

/* determinar el número de filas del resultado */
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

printf($row_cnt);

/* cerrar el resulset */
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Te dejo una parte del código que he modificado. He realizado esto según he entendido tu enunciado. He seleccionado la suma de etiqueta1 y con **AS** le he puesto un "mote". Y lo buscamos en escan1, he quitado la condición ya que si estas metiendo valores de 40 en 40, no es necesario buscar que sean iguales a 40, ya que por defecto lo van a ser.

De nuevo,espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: supongo que debo desabilitar los row_cnt ya probe parte del codigo pero no me muestra la suma en el el diplay de php saludos